# Both variable value getting changed while updating value of second variable

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, object

I've implemented for manipulating Date but I'm getting below output. Can you please explain me why this happening and also provide solution for that.

HTML :

```
<html>
<script>
        const d= new Date();
        console.log(d);
        let a=d;
        a =new Date(a.setDate(d.getDate() + 2));
        console.log(a);
        console.log(d);
</script>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Wed Aug 25 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Fri Aug 27 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Fri Aug 27 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Expected Output :

```
Wed Aug 25 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Fri Aug 27 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Wed Aug 25 2021 17:23:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Thank You.

Comment: `setDate` mutates the date object

Comment: I've used setDate with object a,not with d. so why d is getting changed.

Comment: Because `a` is simply a reference to `d` after you did `let a=d;`

Comment: And also you edited your code after my comment! You were calling `d.setDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript when you assign value of a variable which contain and object you are not creating a copy of that variable by you pass the reference to the initial object. At the end you will only have two variables both storing the reference to the same object.

As both refer to the same object, when you update one of them it will update their reference and which will cause the update of other variable pointing to the same reference.

If you want to copy you can rely on [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: *object.assign* does not make a new Date instance for Date objects, it just copies own enumerable properties not the special properties of Date instances such as the internal time value. Copying a Date should be done like `let date2 = new Date(+date1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2)` **changes** the value of `d`. Instead of doing that, create `a` from the base value of `d` and then modify `a`:

```
    let a = new Date(d);
    a.setDate(a.getDate() + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You written a=d, So both having same value.

Try

```
<script>
        const d= new Date();
        console.log(d);
        var a = new Date(d);
        a.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
        console.log(a);
        console.log(d);
</script>
```

Hope it will work, still face any issue please tall me, I will write article for you on

> codingvila.com

with detail level explanation.

Comment: but after that I've change value of a only. so why value of d being changed.

Comment: Dear Hiren, normal JavaScript not following concept of object oriented programing concept as like typescript, So in your case your constant variable d store their value to variable a, and your a variable you just adding 2 days on same object, so ultimately your object is same for both a and d so while you change value in your object it will reflect all it's related valuable, I changes my answer look there.

Accept it if it works for you.